# Infinite type error when returning a self-referential function in haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite

I'm trying to create a function that returns itself in a tuple of values.  Basically the idea is that the caller would get back transformed values, along with a new (curried) version of the function to use further along in the processing.

However, at the moment, I'm stuck trying to come up with a no-op (i.e. do-nothing) version of this function. So the following snippet is obviously fine - this is a no-op which doesn't return itself:

```
noOp s as xs = (s, as, xs)
```

But if I change to this:

```
noOp s as xs = (s, as, xs, noOp)
```

I get the "infinite type" error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t3 = t0 -> t1 -> t2 -> (t0, t1, t2, t3)
In the expression: noop
In the expression: (s, as, xs, noop)
In an equation for `noop': noop s as xs = (s, as, xs, noop)
```

There's plenty of discussion on SO about handling the infinite type error - but I can't quite figure out how to apply to my problem.

Any advice welcomed...

Comment: Why in the first place you want to return the same function again ?

Comment: Try writing the the type and you will understand why ghc complains.

Comment: Introduce a new type (`data` or `newtype`) somewhere to make the a recursive type.  E.g., make a new type for the return type of `noOp`.

Comment: I'm returning the same function again, because the normal use will be a curried function which takes an argument with some state info. So the basic idea is that the real (not the no-op version) function will return a new version of the itself with different state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To express something like this, you'd need a recursive type. Since Haskell doesn't support [equirecursive types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirecursive_type), you'll need to use `newtype`/`data`.

So you might define `newtype Foo s = Foo { runFoo :: s -> (s, Foo s) }`, for instance, and then write `noOp :: Foo (A,B,C); noOp = Foo (\(a,b,c) -> ((a,b,c), noOp))`.

This looks like a [Mealy machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine). The package `machines` [exports](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/machines/0.2.3.1/doc/html/Data-Machine-Mealy.html) a similar type: `newtype Mealy i o = Mealy { runMealy :: i -> (o, Mealy i o) }`

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand how to use that.  How would I create a new Foo, call the noOp func, and then extract the tuple of a,b,c and noOp fund from the return?  With apologies for the stupid question -  I'm new to Haskell, and working through the tutorials while trying experiments for myself...

Comment: I gave an example there. It'll compile if you change `(A,B,C)` to some types you actually have. E.g. for `Int` state, you can write `noOp :: Foo Int; noOp = Foo (\x -> (x, noOp))`. Then `noOp :: Foo Int`. To get a function out of it, you can just use `runFoo`: `runFoo noOp :: Int -> (Int, Foo Int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering what @augustss was trying to say. The way to go is to use recursive types like

```
data Foo a = Foo a (a -> Foo a)
noop :: a -> Foo a
noop a = Foo a noop
```

Comment: For what it's worth, relating to my answer, this `Foo` is a [Moore machine](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/machines/0.2.3.1/doc/html/Data-Machine-Moore.html). `data Moore i o = Moore o (i -> Moore i o)`. But you can also define these in terms of each other: `Mealy i o = i -> Moore i o`; `Moore i o = (o, Mealy i o)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you have an infinitely recursive type! The type
of noOp is something along the lines of

```
noOp :: a -> b -> c -> (a,b,c,a -> b -> c -> (a,b,c,a -> b -> c -> (a,b,c,...))))
```

As you can see, we can never fully write out the type of `noOp` because it relies
on the type of `noOp`. If only we could encapsulate the type of `noOp` we could
refer to it by name.

But, in fact, we can do that!

```
data Foo a b c = Foo (a -> b -> c -> (a,b,c,Foo a b c))
```

As you can see, the recursion is captured because we refer to the type
by `Foo a b c`. Now it is necessary to wrap and unwrap:

```
runFoo (Foo f) = f

noOp s as xs = Foo (s, as, xs, noOp)
```

Now, I agree, this seems a bit inconvenient, but for a real application you
could possibly find a more suitable data structure than `Foo` to hold your 
values, possibly something along the lines of

```
data Bar s as xs = Bar s as xs (Bar s as xs)
```